# Running time and memory

Tags: memory, big-o

If you cannot see the code of a function, but know that it takes arguments.  Is it possible to find the running time speed and memory.  If so how would you do it.  Is there a way to use Big O in this case?

Comment: If you can run it, there are lots of options. Run it using callgrind and see behavior. Pass various different arguments and see if function behavior changes. You are not seeing code inside, you are just changing external environment.

Comment: @Jack: though I am voted down, look at my answer why this approach will not solve the problem (hence it does not handle O(infinity) functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is an interview question, so you'd better never say no.

---

If I were in the interview, here is my approach.

I may ask the interviewer a few questions, as an interview is meant to be interactive.

Because I cannot see the code, I suppose I can at least run it, hopefully, multiple times. This would be my first question: can I run it? (If I cannot run it, then I can do literally nothing with it, and I give up.)

What is the function used for? This may give a hint of the complexity, if the function is written sanely.

What are the type of argument? Are some they primitive types? Try some combinations of them. Are some of them "complex" (e.g. containers)? Try some different size combinations. Are some of them related (e.g. one for a container, and one for the size of the container)? Some test runs can be saved. Besides, I hope the legal ranges of the arguments are given, so I won't waste time on illegal guesses. Last, to test some marginal cases may help.

Comment: @Dante: the point is to see if you can make a reduction to HP problem, which is known as unsolveable (see my answer for details).

Comment: @amit, we cannot see the code. Thus we have to make some guesses. If it cannot be finished in a threshold time, I just consider it as O(infinite). By the way, this is actually covered in my answer (if the interviewer tells me something about HP, as it is **interactive**). "What is the function used for?"

Comment: @Dante: define "threshold time". how would you tell if it is O(infinity) or O(100^n^n)?

Comment: @amit, sounds like a tough interviewer? I would say: according my knowledge so far, (I have probably known what the function is used for, and what the machine runs it,) I would decide a threshold. For example, the function is used to find a 1000th Fibonacci (take one argument as 1000), I guess it won't take more than 1 minute in a main-stream computer. If it keeps running after 1 minute, I would (at least) say something is wrong with the function.

Comment: @Dante: sometimes they ask for problems with no solutions, my friend was asked: "how can you find an element in an unsorted list in a better complexity then O(n)" - which is impossible. and "impossible" was the right answer.

Comment: This seems like a trick question.  I found some very non big o related way to solve the problem.  However, they all have major problems

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to find either the memory or performance of a function by just looking at its parameters. For example, the same function

```
void DoSomething(int x, int y, int z);
```

Can be implemented as O(1) time and memory:

```
void DoSomething(int x, int y, int z) { }
```

or as a very, very expensive function taking O(x*y*z):

```
void DoSomething(int x, int y, int z)
{
  int a = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
        a++;
      }
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

And many other possibilities. So, it's not possible to find how expensive the function is.

Comment: It's only impossible if you cannot run the function, or if you can only run it a small number of times.

Comment: Interesting, that is what I thought.  It is an interview questions and I was thinking that it is a trick question

Comment: It's impossible even if you can run it many times. imagine for example one function which will take a different action depending on an external source (file, random number, current temperature, etc.). You can only determine the *algorithmic* complexity of a function if you know its algorithm :-)

Answer (score 2):

Am I allowed to run the function at all? Multiple times?

I would execute the function with a range of parameter values and measure the running time and (if possible) the memory consumption for each run. Then, assuming the function takes `n` argument, I would plot each data point on an `n+1`-dimensional plot and look for trends from there.

Comment: how this solution handles O(infinity) problem? (hint: it does not)

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the function with a code? something like this:

```
start = clock();
//call the function;
end = clock();
time = end-start;
```

Comment: It makes sense, but not the most scientific way of doing it.

Comment: how this solution handles O(infinity) problem? (hint: it does not)

Answer (score 1):

Being an interview question, you should never answer like "no it cannot be done".

What you need is the ability to run the code. Once you can run the code, call the same function with different parameters and measure the memory and time required. You can then plot these data and get a good estimate.

For big-O type notations also, you can follow the same approach and plot the results WRT the data set size. Then try to fit this curve with the known complexity curves like n, n^2, n^3, n*log(n), (n^2)*log(n) etc using a least square fit.

Lastly, remember that all these methods are approximations only.

Comment: see my answer why 'no' is the right answer for this question. also, see comments under @Dante`s answer about discussion: "should you never answer no in an interview question?"

Comment: @amit, while it may be true that the interviewer was looking for deep CS concepts like the HP, I feel that an approximate answer is always better than saying no. Many of the problems in CS are NP hard or unsolvable, but in real world we have to make do with whatever closest approximation we can manage.

Comment: this is not P/NP problem, this is R/RE problem. I would go for a no (with the reason of Halting Problem) and then say if we know the program will eventually end, it might be possible to get a heuristic. though I am pretty sure the interviewer was looking to hear about HP in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot, this would have solved the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) , since code might run endlessly O(infinity). thus, solving this problem also solves HP, which is of course proven to be impossible.

Comment: I would appritiate a comment from who voted me down so I'll be able to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your O(infinity) example's unnecessarily pessimistic.  If I'd assigned you the task of estimating the complexity of some function and you came back saying it was impossible to do so in the general case so you wouldn't attempt this specific one, I wouldn't be very happy at all....  The important thing is the practical approach to attempting to find the best possible answer.  Whether that approach is bullet-proof is good to know, but may of no more interest than that the computer could be struck by lightning before the benchmark runs complete....